# Automatic status on 2 models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am stuck since 2 days on a problem that I haven't think before.

To be simple, I manage 3 models (Motorbike, Revision, Training).

If a motorbike is in revision or in training, I have to see on my form Motorbike that the moto is unavailable.

Example:

There are a training on `10/08/2019` with the motorbike `00004`.

[image]

In my form `Motorbike`, the status has changed in `unavailable` for the motorbike `000004`.

[image]

Well !

Now, my problem is in my form `Revision`, if I add a revision for the motorbike `000002`

[image]

**the status has to change** in my form `Motorbike` also. 
Here the status has not changed...

[image]

In my Controller Motorbike I have this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $motorbikes = Motorbike::oldest()->paginate(5);

        $bikeIdsDown = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<=" , Carbon::now())->where('date_revision_end', ">=", Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();

        $bikeIdsDown = Training::where('date_sitting', "<=" , Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();

        return view('admin.motorbikes.index', compact('motorbikes', 'bikeIdsDown'))
          ->with('i', (request()->input('page',1) -1)*5);
    }
```

But, I think my problem is in my index.blade

```
@foreach($motorbikes as $motorbike)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$motorbike->matriculation }} </td>
    <td>{{$motorbike->number_motorbike}}</td>
    <td> @if(in_array($motorbike->id, $bikeIdsDown))
         UNAVAILABLE
         @else
         Available
         @endif
    </td>
```

My array is used only for a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happing with you because you are overriding the same variable.

```
 $bikeIdsDown = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<=" , Carbon::now())->where('date_revision_end', ">=", Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();

 $bikeIdsDown = Training::where('date_sitting', "<=" , Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();
```

you are using a $bikeIdsDown variable for both query response.

change the $bikeIdsDown variable to an array to assign a new value.

```
 $bikeIdsDown = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<=" , Carbon::now())->where('date_revision_end', ">=", Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();

 $bikeIdsDown[] = Training::where('date_sitting', "<=" , Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();
```

or create a new array and merge like :

```
 $revisionId = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<=" , Carbon::now())->where('date_revision_end', ">=", Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();

 $trainingId = Training::where('date_sitting', "<=" , Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();

$bikeIdsDown = array_merge($revisionId, $trainingId);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Vikramjit SIngh, I understood